# Golang - zero value byte array

Tags: json, http, go, arrays

In Golang, zero values are used in case of an error. Eg, if a key is absent in a map[int]string, an empty string is returned.

I'm writing a function that takes in a url and returns the json string received on making an http request. If the error is not null, I would like to set the return value for the body to be a zero value byte array. Since a byte array can be cast into other data types, I can't figure out what to set it as. Maybe context dependent? Since I expect the returned value to be a string, I should set it to an empty string?

Answer (score 3):

No, zero values are not idiomatically used as in-band error values. Map returns a zero value for keys not present, but that's an (often used) feature as one can, if required, test for the presence by the alternative syntax

```
v, ok := m[k]
```

Use multiple return values to return a value *and* a signal at the same time.

To signal a simple (true/false, ok/not ok, ...) condition, use a boolean value.

To signal an error condition, use an `error` typed value.

Etc.

BTW: The Go programming language has *no* casts. It has conversions and they're not the same as casts.